# How to achieve Count(Distinct {x}) from dataTable using c#?

Tags: c#, datatable, listbox

I want to find out the count of the distinct values of a particular column of a DataTable and store the result in listbox.

---

Currently, I have the code to extract the distinct values of a column of a DataTable and store it in a ListBox as follows:-

```
 var ids = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(s => new
                    {
                        EventID = s.Field<Int32>("ID"),
                    })
                    .Distinct().ToList();

               listBox.DataSource = ids;
```

where dt is the name of the DataTable

### ID is the name of the column

For Eg:-

Table is

```
 Name   ID    Marks
 Ashish 10     200
 Ram    100    300
 Sur    200    800
 Shim   10     899
 Kam    100    989
```

Then the result in the listbox should appear as:-

```
{ID=10}{Count=2}
{ID=100}{Count=2}
{ID=200}{Count=1}
```

Currently I am getting output as:-

```
{ID=10}
{ID=100}
{ID=200}
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var idCounts = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("ID"))
    .Select(g => new
    {
        EventID = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count()
    })
    .ToList();

listBox.DataSource = idCounts;
```